# What is the difference between sort() and sort.list() in R?

Tags: r

Well, having decided to get to know some of the basic functions in R I've stumbled upon the `sort.list()` function. I get the pretty straight forward `sort()` function, but don't get the idea of the `sort.list()`. I've read that it should be a permutation function rearranging the content of my vector (in some way).

Having the vector;

```
x <- c(5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.2, 0.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.2)
```

Running `sort.list(x)` outputs

```
[1] 5 3 8 4 9 2 7 1 6
```

Where did that come from? Can someone give me a hint please? And what's the use of this permutation anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sort.list`, as it says at `?sort.list`, is the same as `order`, only instead of accepting multiple arguments via `...`, it accepts only one atomic vector as an argument.

Presumably, then, it could be intended as a "faster" or "simpler" version of `order`.

What good is it? Consider this:

```
x <- c(5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.2, 0.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.2)
> x[sort.list(x)]
[1] 0.0 2.0 2.0 2.2 2.2 3.0 3.0 5.0 5.0
> x[order(x)]
[1] 0.0 2.0 2.0 2.2 2.2 3.0 3.0 5.0 5.0
```

Just like `order` it returns a permutation that when used to index the original vector sorts it.

But I also think the name is confusing.

Comment: Thanks! I did read ?sort.list, but failed to grasp the idea of it. I get it now. Guess I didn't catch the (obvious) relation of the return value of sort.list() to the positions of the value in sorted order...

Comment: @Alex It took me quite a while of having to look up `rank`, `order` and `sort` each time I used them before I could keep it straight in my head what each one did.